# what is storage slot in forge-std and how to set specific number for it？

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity

I'm try to write smart contract based on forge-std, and writing some test by solidity looks like this:

```
function testOutOfToken() public {
    vm.store(
        address(nftToken),
        bytes32(uint256(7)),
        bytes32(uint256(10000))
    );

    vm.expectRevert(abi.encodeWithSignature("MaxSupplyReached()"));

    nftToken.mintNft{value: 0.15 ether}(1);
}
```

the second parameter is *bytes32(uint256(7))*, from the document is explained like this:

```
// Stores a value to an address' storage slot, (who, slot, value)
function store(address,bytes32,bytes32) external;
```

but I still don't understand what **storage slot** is, if I change the 7 to some other number like 8, the test won't pass. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each property of a contract can have some value, and the value is stored in a predetermined location - in a predetermined slot.

For 256bit scalar types, the slot ID is calculated simply by the property position in the code. Smaller types are packed into the same slot (used to be separate in older Solidity versions). And dynamic types are located in slots determined by a hash.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 numberA = 1; // slot 0
    uint256 numberB = 1; // slot 1
    uint256 numberC = 1; // slot 2

    uint128 numberD = 1; // slot 3
    uint128 numberE = 1; // slot 3

    // length in slot 4
    // values in slot ID determined by hash of the position + offset
    // in this case keccak256(4) + 0, keccak256(4) + 1, and keccak256(4) + 2
    uint256[] numbers;

    constructor() {
        numbers.push(2);
        numbers.push(3);
        numbers.push(4);
    }
}
```

> *if I change the 7 to some other number like 8, the test won't pass*

Most likely the value that your test is checking against, is stored in slot ID 7. And slot ID 8 contains some other value (or the default value of 0). Since the other slot doesn't contain the expected value, the test fails.